# Dynamically display "Next" or "Submit" in Gravity Forms

Tags: jquery, gravity-forms-plugin

I am creating a form with conditional logic:
Option 1: a user will put in just their basic information.
Option 2: if they select a checkbox then they will fill in a series of questions in addition to the basic information.
I would like that all the questions that will be presented in option 2 to be on page two of the form which will only display accordingly. All this works, the issue is that the "Submit" button is on page two not page one, so in option 1 the user does not see a "Submit" button only a "Next" button. [The next will submit the form but my concern is the text and styling of the button]. I need conditional logic on the Submit button so if option 1 is chosen the button will display a Submit button and if they choose option 2 it will display a next button.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the checkbox state, you can change the button's text (its value).
Since you showed no code, here's an minimal example.

```js
$("#more").on("click",function(){
 if ( $(this).prop("checked") ){
  $("#next").val("Next");
 }else{
  $("#next").val("Submit");
 }
});

$("#next").on("click",function(){
 if( $(this).val() == "Submit" ){
  alert("Submit the form now.");
 }else{
  alert("Ask the other questions.");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="more"> Check to answer additionnal question<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="next" value="Submit">
```